# Dynamically loading TokBox Embed script in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, opentok, tokbox

I'm trying to dynamically load the TokBox embed script in my React app when the user clicks a button. The script tag is being added to the DOM and successfully loading but it does not go on to download `opentok.min.js` and thus the video control never renders. Adding the code directly into `index.html` works fine however. What is different about loading the tag dynamically?

Snippit:

```
import Script from 'react-load-script';
...
render() {
   return (
      <div>
         ...
         <div id="otEmbedContainer" style={{width:"300px", height:"300px"}}></div>
         {this.state.showVideo && 
            <Script
             url='https://tokbox.com/embed/embed/ot-embed.js?embedId=MYEMBEDID&room=' + this.state.roomId
            />
         }
      </div>
   )    
);
```

Comment: Debug the network request, maybe your `state.roomId` is undefined (or something) and thus the resource request ends up as a 404

Comment: Request looks good.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? If opentok fails to load, the embed won't run, but the error will be caught and logged.

Answer (score 3):

Response from TokBox support:

> It is noted that when you load embed dynamically. you need to fire following event also after the dynamic loading( this is required for embedded to be loaded as per current design).
>
> ```
> var DOMContentLoaded_event = document.createEvent("Event")
>     DOMContentLoaded_event.initEvent("DOMContentLoaded", true, true)
>     window.document.dispatchEvent(DOMContentLoaded_event).
> ```

I haven't tried this because I switched to use the iframe solution for now but posting here for continuity.